# How to encrypt individual headings in org-mode?

Tags: encryption, emacs, org-mode, gnupg

I have searched everywhere for information on how to use org-crypt to password protect specific headings in org-mode.  Most of the info out there says use org-crypt.  I have added the org-crypt lines to my .emacs without any luck getting it to work.  I think you also have to use gpg but am still unsure.

I have added:

```
(require 'org-crypt)
(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)
(setq org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance (quote ("crypt"))) 
;;  set to nil to use symmetric encryption.
(setq org-crypt-key nil)
```

When I save the file with the crypt tag nothing happens.  I think I am missing some kind of connecting code.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: @piet.t how do i do that?  I just want the info out there to help someone else.

Comment: Just post an answer to your own question, which is totally fine (and encouraged!). Just make sure to fit the posts into the Q&A scheme, which means you should edit your question to be an actual question, and add an answer answering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much internet searching and trial (lots of error) led me to the config below. Essentially you use org-crypt *WITH* gnupg. Keep in mind I am running macOS Sierra and Emacs 25.2 .

Use homebrew to install gnupg: `brew install gnupg2`

Add the following lines to your .emacs. It will allow you to encrypt individual headings in an org-file with a passphrase using the TAG :crypt: when added to the heading and saved `(C-x C-s)`. Upon save there will be a pop-up asking for the passphrase.

```
(require 'epa-file)
(custom-set-variables '(epg-gpg-program  "/usr/local/bin/gpg2"))
(epa-file-enable)

(require 'org-crypt)
(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)
(setq org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance (quote ("crypt"))) 
;;  set to nil to use symmetric encryption.
(setq org-crypt-key nil)
```

For good measure:

```
;; Global Tags
(setq org-tag-alist '(("crypt" . ?c)))
```

That should be it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, installing gnupg and pointing emacs to where it's installed does the trick. However, it seems to only work if I launch from terminal and not from the dock or spotlight - any ideas why this is?